# Issue running Next.js on node.js on nazva.pl hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, deployment, server

I am trying to run Next.js application after the build on remote server with Node.js, but I get this error

> /home/server681096/ftp/***/www/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:42
> throw new Error("> Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root");
> ^
>
> Error: > Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root
> at findPagesDir (/home/server681096/ftp/******/www/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:42:15)
> at initialize (/home/server681096/ftp/******/www/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:67:69)
> at async NextCustomServer.prepare (/home/server681096/ftp/******/www/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:240:28)
>
> Node.js v20.3.1

My app.js

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

//const dev = 'production'
const hostname = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
const port = 8080
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev: true, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler() 

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

And command for start is * "start": "node app.js"*

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node app.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "2.8.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.5",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.5",
    "gsap": "^3.12.2",
    "locomotive-scroll": "^5.0.0-beta.8",
    "next": "14.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sharp": "^0.33.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
    "use-intl": "^3.3.2",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/locomotive-scroll": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "postcss-nesting": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Project files
[image: Project files]

I've tried changing the folder to run the app